# AngularJS directive using another controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

I'm trying to create a directive that will output a HTML-template that is using data from a controller.

In sample.js I've added a module, controller and directive

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.someProperty = true;
})

app.directive("myElement", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {name: "@"},
        template:
            '<div ng-show="someProperty">' +
            '    <p>This element is called {{name}}</p>' +
            '</div>',
        replace : true,
        transclude : false
    }
})
```

I'm using the element with the following HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
         <meta charset="UTF-8">

         <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="sample.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <div><my-element name="Mark"></my-element></div>
        <div><my-element name="Vink"></my-element></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Since the controller is created in the body, I would expect the child-element to be able to use it's properties/methods. But there's no data showing up (without the ng-show, the data shows fine).

In this simplified sample I could move the ng-show to the DOM-element in the HTML, but in my actual application this wouldn't be an option. I really need my directive to be able to use properties (and methods) from my controller.

Is this possible? And what did I miss to get it to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using an isolated scope you have to declare someProperty to use it like this

```
app.directive("myElement", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
          name: "@",
          someProperty: "="
        },
        template:
            '<div ng-show="someProperty">' +
            '    <p>This element is called {{name}}</p>' +
            '</div>',
        replace : true,
        transclude : false
    }
});
```

and you can use it like this

```
<my-element name="Vink" some-property="someProperty"></my-element>
```

Comment: To add to this answer, this is from the angular documentation: "As the name suggests, the isolate scope of the directive isolates everything except models that you've explicitly added to the scope: {} hash object. This is helpful when building reusable components because it prevents a component from changing your model state except for the models that you explicitly pass in."